# CDN font-awesome no funciona correctamente

Tags: html, css, sass, font-awesome

Saludos !!
Tengo el siguiente problema con `font-awesome` donde quiero hacer uso del CDN que nos brinda esta librería pero no consigo el resultado necesario.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
   <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <div>Esto es una prueba de font-awesome</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te falta poner `rel="stylesheet"` en el `link` que hace referencia a font-awesome.

Tiene que quedar así:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>  
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
   <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <div>Esto es una prueba de font-awesome</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cierto gracias, no había caído en cuenta jj :) Saludos !!